# I get nothing when use input function on python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, sublimetext

I am trying something very simple but my code just stuck or it is a problem with the print input function. So this is my code

```
variable = input("Enter something: ")
print(variable)
```

When I run my script e get nothing. This is the output:

```
Enter something: try
```

And it just stuck. Nothing is printed. I do not know what is the problem and do not think that there is a coding problem.

Comment: This code won't alone have the behavior you're describing. How is this being run? Is the code you posted here *literally* what you're running?

Comment: Yep. This is all my code. I have not import anything or add something else and this is why I cannot understand the problem

Comment: Do you press the `enter` key after typing `try`?

Comment: Yes. It just gets on the second line and nothing happens

Comment: So if you create a new Python file with just these two lines of code and run it with `python <filename>.py` on a terminal, you get this behavior?

Comment: @Nikimiskata Again, how are you running it? From the command line? An IDE terminal? A REPL?

Comment: If you are directly running this script with double click on the file then it may be possible that your console will not wait for showing you the output i.e. 'try'. And yes make sure that you pressed enter after typing 'try' (as mentioned above).

Comment: From an ide Sublimetext @Carcigenicate

Comment: try to run it with command prompt or terminal. with command python <filename>.py

Comment: It is working fine on a terminal. But when I try using ides it is same

Comment: @Nikimiskata I've never used sublime. This isn't a problem with your code though. You either aren't looking in the right place to see console output, or there's a problem with your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime text 3 has some build problems with its command palette. I just tried this code with sublime and faced the same problem.

Use command prompt(if windows) or terminal(if linux) with following command:

```
python <filename>.py
```

Or open this file with python IDLE and use *F5* key to run the script.